# Was Apostle Paul a widower?

Tags: paul-apostle, 1-corinthians

In 1 Corinthians 7:8, Apostle Paul mentioned that he was unmarried. Is there any knowledge that he might have been widowed, therefore unmarried at that time?

Comment: What evidence causes you to have that opinion ?

Comment: We do not know if he was married.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE, Eva.  If you're looking for evidence, you may want to edit this in: a sermon delivered in a Baptist Church [Was the Apostle Paul Married?  Yes He Was.  Here's How We Know](https://churchleaders.com/outreach-missions/outreach-missions-articles/321152-was-the-apostle-paul-married-yes-he-was-heres-how-we-know-denny-burke.html) based on a certain interpretation of 1 Cor 7:8-9.  Other support: *gotquestions.org* article [Was the apostle Paul married?](https://www.gotquestions.org/apostle-Paul-married.html).